# C# with regex from HTML read version data

Tags: c#, html, regex

This is my HTML tag as string

```
<span class="version">Version: DEV</span>
```

Now I would like to read version "DEV" back with regex

I try with:

```
 Regex regex = new Regex("\"version\">Version:\\s*([^\\s<]+)\\s*</");
 Match match = regex.Match(data);
```

but regex is always False and I don't get data back

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/860585

Comment: Just remove the last part: </, or escape /. It may be <\\/

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have an extra `<` in your capture `([^\\s<]+)`. If you want to capture word characters, I find it easier to use `\w` versus negating whitespace `[^\s]+`.

Expression alone, no escapes:

```
"version">Version:\s*(\w+)\s*</span>
```

C#:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\"version\">Version:\\s*(\\w+)\\s*</span>");
```